# Show an Icon inside Modal Dialog Box

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I'm completely new to MFC and have been working on this issue for a couple of days now and can't find any solution that works.

**Problem:**

I have a dialog class (Modal Dialog Box) with a style defined in an .rc file (Code below) and get the resource id of the icon (`int m_icon` is the same as `IDR_MAINFRAME`) from another class (OtherClass.rc).
All the text information inside the Dialog Box is set dynamically (Code below) but the same doesn't work with the Icon. The marked Icon in the image below is what I'm trying to set.

The Icon Resource is defined in another .rc file and the LoadImage seems to work as I can set the small Icon in the top left of the window. The only problem is setting the big icon in this image. (Not shown at all, just an empty space)

[image]

OtherClass.rc

```
IDR_MAINFRAME           ICON                    "res\\MyIcon.ico"
```

Dialog.rc

```
ABOUTBOX DIALOGEX 0, 0, 285, 77
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "<<Aboutbox>>"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 0, 0, 0x0
BEGIN
    ICON            ABOUT_ICON, ABOUT_ICON, 11, 10, 21, 20
    LTEXT           "", IDC_STATIC, 40, 10, 163, 8, SS_NOPREFIX
    LTEXT           "<<Package Name 1.00>>", ABOUT_NAME, 40, 20, 163, 8, SS_NOPREFIX
    LTEXT           "<<FileName>>", ABOUT_FILENAME, 40, 30, 163, 8, SS_NOPREFIX

    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "OK", IDOK, 217, 7, 60, 14, WS_GROUP
END
```

Dialog.cpp

```
BOOL AboutDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();

    // Window Title
    SetWindowText(L"About " + m_title);

    // Set Icon
    HICON hIcon = (HICON)LoadImage(GetModuleHandleW(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(m_icon), IMAGE_ICON, 96, 96, LR_DEFAULTCOLOR);
    
    SetIcon(hIcon, TRUE);
    SetIcon(hIcon, FALSE);
    
    // Text
    SetDlgItemText(ABOUT_NAME, m_name);
    SetDlgItemText(ABOUT_FILENAME, m_filename);
    
    return TRUE;
}
```

What I've tried doing is:

```
1. GetDlgItem(ABOUT_ICON)->SetIcon(hIcon, TRUE);
2. SendMessage(WM_SETICON, ICON_BIG, (LPARAM)hIcon);
```

and many more things along those lines but the icon space just remains empty. Neither the `LoadImage` nor the `GetDlgItem(ABOUT_ICON)` returns a `nullptr` (already checked that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't have to do any thing like `SetIcon` or `SendMessage` to get an icon to show. What's wrong is your RC file is wrong. It should look like this:

```
ABOUTBOX DIALOGEX 0, 0, 285, 77
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "<<Aboutbox>>"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 0, 0, 0x0
BEGIN
    ICON            ABOUT_ICON, IDC_STATIC, 11, 10, 21, 20
    LTEXT           "", IDC_STATIC, 40, 10, 163, 8, SS_NOPREFIX
    LTEXT           "<<Package Name 1.00>>", ABOUT_NAME, 40, 20, 163, 8, SS_NOPREFIX
    LTEXT           "<<FileName>>", ABOUT_FILENAME, 40, 30, 163, 8, SS_NOPREFIX

    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "OK", IDOK, 217, 7, 60, 14, WS_GROUP
END
```

Take a look at the `ICON` line after the `BEGIN` line.

You had it as `ABOUT_ICON, ABOUT_ICON, 11, 10, 21, 20`, but the 2nd parameter tells the framework what the ID of the control is. Since you want a `Static` control, you use the ID of `IDC_STATIC` which tells the framework there is no ID, but instead it should create a generic `Static` control.

If this doesn't fix it, I would investigate if `ABOUT_ICON` is wired up correctly, that it actually *is* pointing at an icon.

Also, why are you working in the RC file? MFC gives you a great GUI editor. For example, you could modify it using the UI:

[image: MFC]

Comment: The dialog was designed in the GUI editor. I just had to do some minor adjustments to allow for dynamic updating of the icon. Your solution worked perfectly. After creating a `CStatic` member variable, I just had to `.Create` it and call `.SetIcon` with the `LoadIcon` function above. Thanks

Comment: Visual Studio's resource editor was last usable in VS 2012. With every release since then it deteriorated, to the point where today [it isn't usable **at all**](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/816317/dialog-editor-broken-on-hi-dpi-monitor.html) anymore. Try to run Visual Studio's most recent graphical dialog editor on a dual-monitor system with different scaling factors, and see for yourself, whether *"great GUI editor"* is still an appropriate description. The ability to manually write resource scripts has long been promoted from a useful skill to a mandatory one.

Comment: @IInspectable -- Interesting... I use 96 DPI screen on a single monitor which is why I still think it's wonderful lol Thanks for the heads up, though. I won't promote their editor with such fervor from now on